# How make custom drag event in svg.js

Tags: javascript, events, drag, svg.js

I'm new to programming. I'm making something like vector editor with svg.js
I've read documentation and didn't understand how to make custom events at all.
Can you guys show an example of drag event?

Actually i'm trying to achieve elements to be removed on drag. For example i want to make tooltip following mouse cursor, that outputs current mouse coordinates. But it gets duplicated every onmousemove event.

Answer (score 2):

Use : [draggable plugin](https://github.com/wout/svg.draggable.js)

To make an element draggable

```
var draw = SVG('canvas').size(400, 400)
var el = draw.rect(100, 100)

el.draggable()
```

There are four different callbacks available, `beforedrag`, `dragstart`, `dragmove` and `dragend`. This is how you assign them:

E.g. in your case:

```
el.dragstart = function() {
  this.remove();
}
```

or

```
el.dragsend = function() {
  this.remove();
}
```

or

```
el.dragsmove = function() {
  this.remove();
}
```